# draw in picturebox with scorll mfc c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I want to draw in Picture Box control my purpose is picture box have scroll bar that I can draw in it bigger than what It's size I mean have scroll to move It's picture,
I try to draw something more than picturebox's size, It went to main frame panel my code is below.

```
void Cex133Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CDC *myDC = GetDlgItem(IDC_DRAWBOX)->GetDC();   
    myDC->Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw with in the picture box. Definitely it will go outside the picture box frame, if you draw something more than picturebox's size. For that you can calculate the picture box Size, According to that you will draw your object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't draw to the control -- you give it a bitmap, and it does its own drawing.

Comment: I must only draw line,circle and things like that but can you suggest me another way to draw with scroll.

Comment: @Ali: the obvious choice would be to draw in a CScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can look for http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c14765 and mfc [CScrollView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/cscrollview.aspx)

Comment: nice link but how can I solve my problem about drawing in main panel how can I allot picturebox panel to draw board.

Comment: @Ali you want to add button to window header?

Comment: No,I want to for example have  with paper with scroll that I can draw on it.